# Java Regular Expressions equivalent to PCRE/etc. shorthand `\K`?

Tags: java, regex, equivalent

Perl RegEx and PCRE (Perl-Compatible RegEx) amongst others have the shorthand `\K` to discard all matches to the left of it except for capturing groups, but Java doesn't support it, so what's Java's equivalent to it ?

Comment: Does left part contain variable-length patterns?

Comment: There is no equivalent in Java. However you can obtain what you want using capture groups. Using a lookbehind is sometime possible but it is most of the time less efficient.

Comment: @revo Usually it does.

Comment: @rautamiekka: Please check the answer below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ya, been aware of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There is no direct equivalent**. However, you can always re-write such patterns using *capturing groups*.

If you have a closer look at `\K` operator and its limitations, you will see you can replace this pattern with *capturing groups*.

See [rexegg.com `\K` reference](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K):

> In the middle of a pattern, `\K` says "reset the beginning of the reported match to this point". Anything that was matched before the `\K` goes unreported, a bit like in a lookbehind.
>
> The key difference between `\K` and a lookbehind is that in PCRE, a lookbehind does not allow you to use quantifiers: the length of what you look for must be fixed. On the other hand, `\K` can be dropped anywhere in a pattern, so you are free to have any quantifiers you like before the `\K`.

**However**, all this means that the pattern before `\K` is still *a consuming pattern*, i.e. the regex engine adds up the matched text to the match value and *advances its index* while matching the pattern, and `\K` only drops the matched text from the match keeping the index where it is. This means that `\K` is no better than capturing groups.

So, a `value\s*=\s*\K\d+` PCRE/Onigmo pattern would translate into this Java code:

```
String s = "Min value = 5000 km";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("value\\s*=\\s*(\\d+)").matcher(s);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

There is an alternative, but that can only be used with smaller, simpler
patterns. A [constrained width lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-disambiguation.html#lookbehind_width):

> Java accepts quantifiers within lookbehind, as long as the length of the matching strings falls within a pre-determined range. For instance, `(?<=cats?)` is valid because it can only match strings of three or four characters. Likewise, `(?<=A{1,10})` is valid.

So, this will also work:

```
    m = Pattern.compile("(?<=value\\s{0,10}=\\s{0,10})\\d+").matcher(s);
    if(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/Q1TtwJ).